# Can't select specific element in JSON parsed array with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, json

So I have a mySQL database and I am pulling data from it to my website and want to change content with the help of JavaScript. The problem is that I can't seem to select specific elements out of my data which I received from the databse.

Here is how I pull data and parse it into a JSON string:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $return_array = array("region" => $row['region'], "capital" => $row['capital'], "surface_area" => $row['surface_area'], "land_area" => $row['land_area'], "water_area" => $row['water_area'], "global_area_rank" => $row['global_area_rank'], "land_boundary" => $row['land_boundary'], "bordering_countries" => $row['bordering_countries'], "coastline" => $row['coastline'], "climate" => $row['climate'], "terrain" => $row['terrain'], "avg_elevation" => $row['avg_elevation'], "highest_elevation" => $row['highest_elevation'], "lowest_elevation" => $row['lowest_elevation'], "natural_resources" => $row['natural_resources'], "land_use" => $row['land_use'], "irrigated_land" => $row['irrigated_land'], "natural_hazards" => $row['natural_hazards']);
}
echo json_encode($return_array);
```

In my JavaScript method I call this PHP script and receive the parsed JSON string which I temporarily output in a single div:

```
$.post('ajax/retrieve_data.php', { sel1: sel1, sel2: sel2 }, function(data) {
    var return_array = $.parseJSON(data);
    $('div#test-div').text(return_array.region);
});
```

The output however, just shows the entire JSON string with curly brackets and all identifiers, which means that the `return_array.region` selector does not work. I tried it with indices and all sorts of other syntax, but it did not work. Everywhere on the internet everyone uses this syntax to select specific elements, but it somehow doesn't work. I probably have a very stupid error in there, but I appreciate every help. I just can't seem to see the error.

Comment: Have you tried logging out `data` before running it through `$.parseJSON`? That might reveal a bit more about the structure of the JSON object you're getting from the structure. If you're still running into issues, can you share this output?

Comment: Show us what data stores before/after passing it to `parseJSON`

Comment: PHP supports array with named keys, that's rarely supported by other languages including javascript. So firstly you should inspect on what is actually returned. I doubt that in this case the array will lose its named keys.

Comment: @jeroen ok, I was looking at this part:  `$return_array = array(` - the fact it has 2x "array" in would suggest there might be an array in there somewhere :)

Comment: Add a `console.dir(data)` and `console.dir(return_array)` in the js and post results here (remove sensitive data ofc).

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Somehow, console.dir() does not work at all for me and I can't even put out the data before parsing, but I think it might be the same. However, here is what I get in my testing div after parsing: {"region":"Southern Asia","capital":"Kabul",...}

Comment: @JohannesMols why not try using `JSON.parse`? `$.parseJSON` seems to be deprecated.

Comment: Not sure which browser you're using, but you can fall back to `console.log(data)`.  `.dir` will provide more information than `.log` especially in older IE browsers where `.log` would just give the universally pathetic: "[Object]"

Comment: Yeah, console.log(data) does not put out anything either, I really have no idea why. When I use JSON.parse, it does work too but it doesn't make a difference in the output.

Comment: Try putting in ajax/retrieve_data.php in your address bar manually, and post the *entire* output (censor anything sensitive of course, but even if you have to censor key names / values, keep the structure the same).

Comment: Well it gives out this structure: {"region":"Southern Asia","capital":"Kabul",...} and that's it. I don't understand why it doesn't want to parse into a Array which I can really use though.

Comment: well that means you get an object, not an array. So parsing should be ok.

Comment: yeah, it _should_

Comment: @JohannesMols Open your developer tools and tell us what's the output in network tab. If `console.log(data)` doesn't output anything there must be something wrong with the output of PHP file.

Comment: Yes I figured it out. The problem was that nothing ever changed because the JavaScript file was cached and didn't reload. I cleared my cache and now it works fine. I knew it would be something stupid like that...

Comment: @JohannesMols That's why you always want your developer tools open with "Don't cache if developer tools are active" checked.

Comment: That's great to know, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your PHP script isn't returning data with the proper Content-Type header. Make sure, in your PHP script, you run the following:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

This must come before echoing anything.